# In VSCode remote ssh, how to change the right-click delete action in File Explorer from permanent deletion to moving files to the Recycle Bin?

Tags: ssh, remote, visual-studio-code, recycle-bin, recovery

I connect to remote server by ssh on vscode.
The right-click delete action in File Explorer will permanently delete files of remote server.
How to change the right-click delete action in File Explorer from permanent deletion to moving files to the Recycle Bin of remote server (or some designated file folder of remote server)?

Comment: This is a setting for the target computer. Which operating systems on server & client ?

Comment: I  alias the 'rm' to 'mv to /data/trash', it  can work when I use 'rm' cmd, but it dose not work when I right-click to delete some file in File Explorer of remote ssh.

Comment: how can I achieve my objective?